# Corresponding Regexp In Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp which should detect sequential digits like "123456" or "654321"in c# but cannnot convert it to the corresponding javascript regexp string.

```
string re = @"(?x)
        ^
        # fail if...
        (?!
            # sequential ascending
            (?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){5} \d $
            |
            # sequential descending
            (?:1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $
        )
    ";
```

I tried the following Javascript but it seems to always return true:

```
var re = new RegExp("^(?!(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){5} \d $|(?:1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5} \d $)");
var isMatch = re.test(str);
```

Comment: As I mentioned, remove all spaces. https://regex101.com/r/kNHkMn/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did but it still tests true for both "123456" and "135468".

Comment: `123456` does not match, and `135468` looks valid as per the regex. Same results are obtained at http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Apparently I needed to double the back-slashes as they were evaluated as escape characters.

Comment: Why not just use a function that process the string letter by letter?

Comment: You actually need to just put the pattern as a regex literal, `var re = /^(?!(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){5}\d$|(?:1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\d$)/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the JavaScript regex engine does not support freespace (verbose) regex mode (enabled with the `(?x)` inline modifier) you need to remove all the formatting whitespace from the pattern.

In JS, you'd better use a regex literal notation to avoid the trouble of choosing the right number of backslashes to escape special regex metacharacters:

```
var re = /^(?!(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)){5}\d$|(?:1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8)){5}\d$)/;
```